# using stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
USE [totalsolution]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Fact_Table_coursor4]    Script Date: 03/03/2015 14:36:01 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER  PROCEDURE A
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declaration for variables required in the destination table
    DECLARE @State_cd varchar(15),@District_cd varchar(15),@Block_cd varchar(15),
    @Area_cd varchar(15), @Age_in_years int,@No_of_persons int;
    
    -- Declaration for additional variables required 
    DECLARE @currYear int
    DECLARE @CurrDateTime datetime
    DECLARE @DOB      datetime    
    DECLARE @DOBYear  int    
    DECLARE @Age      int
    DECLARE @House_no varchar(15)
    DECLARE @UID_Head varchar(15)
    DECLARE @UID_Member  varchar(15)
    DECLARE @UID_person  varchar(15)
    
    DECLARE Statewise_Districtwise_Blockwise_Areawise_cursor CURSOR FOR
       select x.state_cd,y.district_cd,z.block_cd,a.area_cd 
              from State x,District y,Block z, Area a
              where x.state_cd=y.state_cd
              and   y.district_cd = z.district_cd
              and   z.block_cd = a.block_cd;

    -- First 4 variables may be obtained from the first table               
    OPEN Statewise_Districtwise_Blockwise_Areawise_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM Statewise_Districtwise_Blockwise_Areawise_cursor 
                    INTO @State_cd,@District_cd,@Block_cd, @Area_cd;

    -- For next 3 variables
    WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
    BEGIN
          -- DECLARE @AgeArray[100] int;
          
          DECLARE Areawise_Housewise_HouseOccupancywise_FamilyMemberwise_Personwise_cursor CURSOR FOR
              select x.area_cd,y.house_no,z.uid_head, f.uid_member, p.UID, p.date_of_birth
              from   Area x,House y,  House_occupancy z, Family_member f, Person p
              where x.area_cd = @Area_cd
              and   y.area_cd = @Area_cd
              and   z.area_cd = @Area_cd
              and   y.house_no = z.house_no 
              and   z.to_date = NULL
              and   z.UID_head = f.UID_Head
              and   f.UID_Member = p.UID;
    
              OPEN Areawise_Housewise_HouseOccupancywise_FamilyMemberwise_Personwise_cursor 
              FETCH NEXT FROM Areawise_Housewise_HouseOccupancywise_FamilyMemberwise_Personwise_cursor 
                          INTO @Area_cd, @House_no, @UID_Head, @UID_Member, @UID_person, @DOB;
          
              WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
              BEGIN                                         
                    select DOBYear = Year (@DOB);
                    select GetDate () as CurrDateTime;
                    select currYear = Year (@CurrDateTime);

                    select @Age = @currYear - @DOBYear;
                    -- AgeArray[Age] = AgeArray [Age]+1;

                    DECLARE DW_Blockwise_Areawise_Agewise_distribution_cursor CURSOR FOR
                         SELECT * FROM dbo.DW_Blockwise_Areawise_Agewise_distribution 
                              WHERE state_code = @State_cd 
                              AND   district_code = @District_cd
                              AND   block_code = @Block_cd
                              AND   area_code = @Area_cd
                              AND   age_in_years = @Age;
                     
                    OPEN DW_Blockwise_Areawise_Agewise_distribution_cursor 
                    FETCH NEXT FROM DW_Blockwise_Areawise_Agewise_distribution_cursor 
                               INTO @Area_cd, @District_cd, @Block_cd, @Area_cd, @Age, @No_of_persons;
                    
                    IF @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 AND @@ROWCOUNT = 1
                    BEGIN
                         UPDATE dbo.DW_Blockwise_Areawise_Agewise_distribution 
                           SET  state_code  = @State_cd,
                                district_code = @District_cd, 
                                block_code = @Block_cd,
                                area_code = @Area_cd,
                                age_in_years = @Age,
                                no_of_persons = @No_of_persons +1
                                
                           WHERE state_code =@State_cd 
                              AND   district_code = @District_cd
                              AND   block_code = @Block_cd
                              AND   area_code = @Area_cd
                              AND   age_in_years = @Age;
                              
                 -----   ELSE       
                           INSERT INTO dbo.DW_Blockwise_Areawise_Agewise_distribution 
                               VALUES (@State_cd,@District_cd,@Block_cd,@Area_cd,@Age_in_years,1) ;                            
                           
                    
                    FETCH NEXT FROM Areawise_Housewise_HouseOccupancywise_FamilyMemberwise_Personwise_cursor 
                          INTO @Area_cd, @House_no, @UID_Head, @UID_Member, @UID_person, @DOB;
                     CLOSE DW_Blockwise_Areawise_Agewise_distribution_cursor;
                     DEALLOCATE DW_Blockwise_Areawise_Agewise_distribution_cursor;     
              END
              CLOSE Areawise_Housewise_HouseOccupancywise_FamilyMemberwise_Personwise_cursor;
              DEALLOCATE Areawise_Housewise_HouseOccupancywise_FamilyMemberwise_Personwise_cursor;
          END 
          FETCH NEXT FROM Statewise_Districtwise_Blockwise_Areawise_cursor
                          INTO @State_cd,@District_cd,@Block_cd, @Area_cd;
     END
     CLOSE Statewise_Districtwise_Blockwise_Areawise_cursor;     

    --- CLOSE Statewise_Districtwise_Blockwise_Areawise_cursor;
   ---  DEALLOCATE DW_Blockwise_Areawise_Agewise_distribution_cursor;
   ---  DEALLOCATE Areawise_Housewise_HouseOccupancywise_FamilyMemberwise_Personwise_cursor;
     DEALLOCATE Statewise_Districtwise_Blockwise_Areawise_cursor;

END
GO

EXEC A;
```

When I execute the stored procedure I get these errors:

> Msg 16915, Level 16, State 1, Procedure A, Line 38
> A cursor with the name Areawise_Housewise_HouseOccupancywise_FamilyMemberwise_Personwise_cursor' already exists.
>
> Msg 16905, Level 16, State 1, Procedure A, Line 48
> The cursor is already open.

Comment: Please fix your formatting.  It's very difficult to tell what you are asking.

Comment: Best solution: ***avoid*** cursors altogether! Stop the **RBAR** (row-by-agonizing-row) processing and upgrade to using nice, fast **set-based** statements instead!

Comment: Gah.  The solution is to **declare** once and reassign with **set**, but this proc is awful.  If you are using cursors, 99% of the time you are doing it wrong w/ regards to SQL.

Comment: The error messages are about as explicit as they can be.  You've run this one, and never deallocated the cursors (why are they commented out at the bottom?) so the next time it runs, the cursor already exists, so the create statement fails.  You also have to close the cursor before deallocating.  But as the others said, it's best to avoid cursors at all if you can. And usually you can.

Comment: Can you solve the error please or write the code